# How to pass Server.HtmlEncode in ajax jquery method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Server.HtmlEncode

to Encode the string, since  it is not support apostrophe

```
Example-"Capacit's Infraprojects Limited" changes  to 
 "Capacit&amp;#39;e" Infraprojects Limited <br>
So I used  Server.HtmlEncode to resolve it 

 <a onclick="setOfferDocument('@Server.HtmlEncode(documents.CompanyName)')"  class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)" 
 >@Server.HtmlDecode(documents.CompanyName)</a>
```

Now I have dropdown where on click of company name it fetch the data
For that I using the ajax function

dropdown-

```
<select id="single-appendSpeaker" onchange="GetSelectedOfferData()" class="select2" style="width:;">    
            <option value="All">All</option>       
                         </select>
```

Ajax function Where I get the name of comapny

```
function GetSelectedOfferData() {
    debugger;
        var companyName = $("#single-appendSpeaker").val();
        if (companyName == "All") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/OfferDocument/getAllOfferDocument",
                data: {},
                success: function (result) {
                    var doc = '';


                    $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                        doc = doc + '<li><a onclick="setOfferDocument(\'' + val.companyName  + '\')"  class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)" >' + val.companyName  + '</a><br /></li>'
                    });
                    $("#ProspectUL").empty();
                    $("#ProspectUL").append(doc);
                }
            });           
         }
        else {
            var data = '';    

            data = data + '<li><a onclick="setOfferDocument(\'' + companyName  + '\')"  class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)" >' + companyName + '</a><br /></li>'
            $("#ProspectUL").empty();
            $("#ProspectUL").append(data);           
        }
    }
```

Now since the name is not matching I am not getting the value,
for that i need to encode this value
eg- Capacit's Infraprojects Limited to Capacit&#39;e" Infraprojects Limited

Then only it will match and I will get the data...

I tried to

```
 doc = doc + '<li><a onclick="setOfferDocument(\'' + @Server.HtmlEncode(val.companyName)  + '\')"  class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)" >' +@Server.HtmlEncode(val.companyName)  + '</a><br /></li>'
                        });
```

Not Working

Comment: wouldn't using some kind of company Id make a lot more sense than the name?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Regular expression  to replace '
eq:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/'/g);
var s = "Capacit's";
console.log(s.replace(regexp, "&#39;e"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use `JavaScriptStringEncode` so replace

```
<a onclick="setOfferDocument('@Server.HtmlEncode(documents.CompanyName)')"...
```

with:

```
<a onclick="setOfferDocument('@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(documents.CompanyName))')"
```

Also note the usage of `@Html.Raw(...)`. This  will prevent MVC from appying html encode when rendering the output.

Secondly, to fix your code building the li items I suggest using an approach like this:

```
$('<a class="link-download" href="javascript:void(0)">').click(function(){ setOfferDocument("" + companyName)} );
```

Comment: I am getting Encoded value has Capacit&#39;e I want it to decode    Capacit'e

Comment: And When I am using your code click event is not working

Comment: Are you sure you removed your call to HtmlEncode and you are also using   @Html.Raw(...)? That should just emit Capacit\u0027e when using JavascriptEncode

Just try putting below code to your view and then inspect page source or call `alert(a);` from within havascript console: 
`<script>var a = '@Html.Raw( System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("Capacit'e"))';</script>`